# Angular 4 universal embedded in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, angular, angular-universal

I have wordpress website that has the product section build in angular 4. The site is not entirely build in angular. Is it possible to use universal to pre-render those angular 4 widgets on the server or does universal only works if the site entirely in angular?

Thanks
Olaf

Comment: Universal is a web server for NodeJS that allows routes to be browsed by web crawlers.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the hosting environment.

Basically, you need to configure WordPress to ignore the root URL of your angular app (e.g. MySite.com/products), and then you need your web server (IIS / Apache / ?) to have that route configured to deliver your angular app.

Specific details depend on what host you use and whether it can run node server in this shared environment as Angular Universal runs on node server

Comment: Thanks, I run a AWS Centos instance, this should not hold me back. The problem is that the angular app is actually embedded on a wordpress page. I can gather I the entire page must be angular?

Comment: You need an entire directory (root url) for the angular app, which can be inside the root sirectory of the wordpress app.

Comment: The only alternative is to put the angular app inside an IFrame in the wordpress page